# Haskell cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to solve the second problem on Project Euler using Haskell. The problem is fairly straight forward - sum the even fibonacci numbers less then 4000000. (Me being OCD, I'm implimenting a slightly modified function - one which allows an arbitraty limit).

My initial code was:

```
euler2 limit (num1:num2) 
    |(num1>limit) = 0
    |((num2>limit) && ((mod num1 2) == 0)) = num1
    |(num2>limit) = 0
    |(((mod num1 2) == 0) && ((mod num2 2) == 0)) = num1+num2+(euler2 limit [num1+num2,num1+num2+num2])
    |((mod num1 2) == 0) = num1+(euler2 limit [num1+num2,num1+num2+num2])
    |((mod num2 2) == 0) = num2+(euler2 limit [num1+num2,num1+num2+num2])
    |otherwise = euler2 limit [num1+num2,num1+num2+num2]
euler2 limit [] = euler2 limit [1,2]
```

Which produced the following error:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
In the second argument of `(>)', namely `limit'
In the first argument of `(&&)', namely `(num2 > limit)'
In the expression: ((num2 > limit) && ((mod num1 2) == 0))
```

Now through some trial and error, I have realized that it is attempting to typecast `num2` as a list, and this small change:

```
euler2 limit (num1:num2:[]) | (num1 > limit) = 0
```

fixes the problem. My question is why? What is going on and why was it refusing to cast `num1` and `num2` as Ints?

Comment: Try adding an explicit type signature to your euler2 function: `euler2 :: Integer [Integer]` (or something like that...). Fixing the types can lead to simpler error messages.

Comment: `num1` is an `Int`, your problem is that `num2` is not; it is a list of `Ints`.

Comment: right but explicitly stating the :[] feels like a dirty dirty hack. Is there any way to enforce this sort of thing more elegantly? What would be the "Haskell way"?

Comment: @AbrahamP `[num1, num2]`

Comment: @AbrahamP Why would pattern matching on `(:[])` be a hack? Branching on your data structure is what pattern matching is for. As to your last question: Haskell will never implicitly coerce types. If you wanted, you could extract the first element of `num2` using `head`, but you have no guarantee that calling `head` is safe in that situation.

Comment: The list you're iterating on seems to have always length 2. You can use a tuple instead: write `(num1,num2)`. Yet another option would be to simply have two parameters of type `Int` instead of a list.

Comment: [num1, num2] is fantastic. As for the tuples idea, I tried that at first, but ran into
Equations for `euler2' have different numbers of arguments. {Which they did euler2 limit called euler2 limit (1,2)}

Comment: your function tries to do all the things mixed up in one place - fused into one function: generating Fib numbers, testing them for evenness, summing them up... Because it's all jumbled up together it's harder to *not* make a mistake. You try to be more efficient and go up by two steps each time, but that makes your code harder to follow. The Haskell way is *separation of concerns*: `genfibs (a,b) = a:genfibs(b,a)`; and then `eu2 = sum . filter even . takeWhile (< 4000000) . genfibs $ (0,1)`. It's harder to make a mistake that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `(:)` is

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

If you have a pattern match

```
euler2 limit (num1:num2)
```

the names `num1` and `num2` are bound to the corresponding arguments of the constructor `(:)` (if the supplied argument is a nonempty list), thus `num2` is a list whose elements have the type of `num1`.

If you match on

```
(num1:num2:[])
```

that is implicitly parenthesized

```
(num1 : (num2 : []))
```

and now `num2 : []` is matched with the list that is the second argument of the top-level `(:)`, and that match succeeds, binding `num2` to the second list element, if the supplied argument is a list with exactly two elements.

Comment: just would add implicit right associativity of (:) operator/list constructor is due to its right fixity